# Why spring boot boot not indicates that connection string removed from yml file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I work on a java spring boot project.
I have an application.yml file that contains the connection string:

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
     uri: mongodb://localhost:27017/development
```

I comment on connection string rows in the application.yml file:

```
#spring:
#  data:
#    mongodb:
#  uri: mongodb://localhost:27017/development
```

And then I rebuild the project and trigger repository functions.

To my surprise, I do not get any exceptions or errors while the repositories are executed and application.yml has commented connection string.

The result that I get from repository functions is an empty result.

So my question is very simple, why i do not get any indications on a runtime that the connection string is removed does spring create some default connection in case it cannot find the conn string in yml file?

Comment: As documented it defaults to `mongodb://localhost/test`. It is in the list of properties and specified with a default.

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you for the post. Can you please attach a link to the document?

Comment: It is documented in the Spring Boot reference guide at least in the section explaining the differnt properties. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#appendix.application-properties.data

Answer (score -1):

I can't say if there is anything specific with Mongo, but for Spring in general you can create typesafe config and validate it on startup.

application.yml

```
myapp:
  mongo-uri: mongodb://localhost:27017/development 

spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
     uri: ${myapp.mongo-uri}
```

MyAppProperties.java

```
@Validated
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myapp")
public class MyAppProperties {
  @NotEmpty
  private String mongoUri;
  // accessors
}
```

In @Configuration's or @SpringBootApplication

`@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyAppProperties.class)`

The key things are @Validated and @NotEmpty. You will get startup error if `${myapp.mongo-uri}` is not provided.

Comment: Doing this duplicates what Spring already does, and doesn't make a lot of sense.